# Create ftp user in Windows server 2008 using php

Tags: php, ftp

i have a site that provides an option to upload user's files using ftp. 
when i was working in cPanel, i used the cpanel api that gave option to create ftp users. Now i am on Windows server, and i have no idea how to do the same - create ftp user using php. The server running IIS 7 if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! there is an awesome tool called xlight ftp and you can manage ftp users through Mysql, and it's easy to make sql queries in php. here is the full guide: http://www.xlightftpd.com/tutorial/usersODBC.html